# Storing hexadecimal addresses in a file

Tags: c++, file-io, hex

I have a pintool application which store the memory address accessed by an application in a file. These addresses are in hexadecimal form. If I write these addresses in form of string, it will take a huge amount of storage(nearly 300GB). Writing such a large file will also take large amount of time. So I think of an alternate way to reduce the amount of storage used.

Each character of hexadecimal address represent 4 bits and each ASCII character is of 8 bits. So I am thinking of representing two hexadecimal characters by one ASCII character.

For example :
if my hexadecimal address is **0x26234B** 
then corresponding converted ASCII address will be **&#K** (0x is ignored as I know all address will be hexadecimal).

I want to know that is there any other much more efficient method for doing this which takes less amount of storage.

NOTE : I am working in c++

Comment: If you are just storing addresses and not what's in those addresses, why not just store ranges: 0x1234-0x4567?

Comment: Why not convert the hex notation to binary and store that.

Comment: @Johnny I need addresses as i have to convert them back to hexadecimal values in order to carry out my analysis so storing only ranges in not at all an option for me.

Comment: @Steger Compressing that txt file to binary is second step of my process but in first step I need a txt file containing hexadecimal addresses.

Comment: It looks like your addresses are hex encoding 24 bits using 8 characters (8 bytes). Instead you could directly store each address in 3 bytes. Of course if you need 32 bits then simple store each address in 4 bytes. About as compact as you can get!

Comment: Do you understand the difference between hexadecimal and the number (memory address) it represents?  It seems not.  What you are doing isn't compressing two hexadecimal digits into a byte, it's simply avoiding using an inefficient string representation in the first place.

Comment: @Ben yes i know that this is not compression. But i want to generate a txt file in order to carry out my analysis

Comment: @Vijay: Create the text representation when you view the file, not when you write it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start. If you really want to go further, you can consider compressing the data using something like a zip library or Huffman encoding.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* your addresses are 64-bit pointers, and that such a representation is sensible for your platform, you can just store them as 64-bit ints. For example, you list `0x1234567890abcdef`, which could be stored as the four bytes:

```
12 34 56 78 90 ab cd ef
(your pointer, stored in 8 bytes.)
```

or the same, but backwards, depending on what [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) you choose. Specifically, you should read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Examples_of_storing_the_value_0A0B0C0Dh_in_memory).

We can even do this somewhat platform-independently: `uintptr_t` is unsigned integer type the same width as a pointer (assuming one exists, which it usually does, but it's not a sure thing), and `sizeof(our_pointer)`, which gives us the size in bytes of a pointer. We can arrive at the above bytes with:

1. Convert the pointer to an integer representation (i.e., `0x0026234b`)
2. Shift the bytes around to pick out the one we want.
3. Stick it somewhere.

In code:

```
unsigned char buffer[sizeof(YourPointerType)];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(YourPointerType); ++i) {
    buffer[i] = (
        (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(your_pointer) >> (sizeof(YourPointerType) - i - 1))
        & 0xff
    );
}
```

Some notes:

1. That'll do a `>> 0` on the last loop iteration. I suspect that might be undefined behavior, and you'll need an if-case to handle it.
2. This will write out pointers of the size of your platform, and requires that they can be converted sensibly to integers. (I think `uintptr_t` won't exist if this isn't the case.) It won't do the same thing on 64- as it will on 32-bit platforms, as they have different pointer sizes. (Or any other pointer-sized platform you run across.)
3. A program's pointers aren't valid once the program dies, and might not even remain valid when the program is still running. (If the pointer points to memory that the program decides to free, then the pointer is invalid.)

There's likely a library that'll do this for you. (`struct`, in Python, does this.)

The above is a big-endian encoder. Alternatively, you can write out little endian — the Wikipedia article details the difference.

Last, you can just cast a pointer to the pointer to a `unsigned char *`, and write that. (I.e., dump the actual memory of the pointer to a file.) That's way more platform dependent though.

If you need even more space, I'd run it through `gzip`.

Comment: Thank for explaining your approach in detail but i think it won't help me as i am working on 64 bit system.

Comment: The approach works exactly the same on 64-bit systems; they're just twice as big (8 bytes, as opposed to 4). The listed code should work on both, I've edited the examples to match.

Comment: The address which generate on 64 bit machine contains 14 characters (including 0x). Hence by my approach I require only 6 bytes to encode them and by your approach I need 8 bytes.

Comment: You are both proposing the same solution. Thanatos is simply rightfully calling them bytes (binary is implied here) and Vijay is calling them 8-bit ASCII characters. If you only need to store 48 bits then you can code them in 6 bytes, making use of all 8'bits in each byte. AKA binary!

Comment: I wouldn't get too cushy assuming those top two are always zero, but feel free to do so. (But please, document it.)